# Place element at each corner of minipage

Tags: positioning, minipage, coordinates, picture-mode

##### General overview

I try to put different elements on each corner of a minipage.

##### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{calc} 



\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}{8.5cm}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
    \begin{picture}(0,0)

        \put(-0.5,0){\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}} % NO
        \put(8.5,0){\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-b}} %NE
        \put(-0.5,-\textheight){\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-c}} %SO
        \put(8.5,-7){\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}} % SE

    \end{picture}

    \noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

##### Rendering

[image: Rendering]

##### The problem

As you see, I can define the horizontal position because I know the total width (as `minipage` environment force me to declare it). But I can’t know by advance the height of a minipage.

Ideally I should be able to catch this value inside a variable to use it in the coordinate. Instead I used `\textheight` but it give the height of the wool page text, and not just of the minipage box.

##### The question(s)

1. How to catch the height of minipage inside a variable to use it inside the minipage itself?
2. *Alternatively*, how to put an element in each corner by another way?

Comment: The four graphics should he on the outside of the minipage? Outside of that 8cm? But still contribute to the height/width of the whole construct?

Comment: To answer question 1, use `\setbox\foo=\vbox{...}`  and use `\wd\foo`, `\ht\foo` and `\dp\foo`.   Use `\usebox\foo` to print the contents, where `\foo` is a savebox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tikzmark` library of the `tikz` package  allows addressing and placing material in the four corners of a `tikz` node, as seen in this example.

See [tikzmark](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzmark/tikzmark.pdf) doc (many examples).

The command  `\tikzmarknode{<name>}{<content>}` command will output the  *content* and also create a Tikz node named *name*.

You can then put any other material in its corners using the *name.north east* nomenclature for the top right corner; *name.south west* for the bottom left corner, etc.

Obviously the two steps can be merged by defining a new command or a new environment.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    
\usepackage{tikz}% <<<<<<<<<<<
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}% <<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\tikzmarknode{mini}{\begin{minipage}{8.5cm}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\end{minipage}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]  
    \node at (mini.north east) {X}; 
    \node at (mini.north west) {X};     
    \node at (mini.south east) {X};
    \node at (mini.south west) {X};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the following example, four images are added with some x-y offset.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    
\usepackage{tikz}% <<<<<<<<<<<
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}% <<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\tikzmarknode{mini}{\begin{minipage}{8.5cm}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\end{minipage}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]  
    \node[shift={(1em, 1ex)}, at=(mini.north east)] {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-b}};
    \node[shift={(-1em, 1ex)}, at=(mini.north west)] {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}};
    \node[shift={(1em, -1ex)}, at=(mini.south east)] {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}};
    \node[shift={(-1em, -1ex)}, at=(mini.south west)] {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-c}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can simplify writing of the *xy offset* by adding an internal space to the node. Try

```
\tikzmarknode[inner sep=1ex]{mini}{\begin{minipage}{8.5cm}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\end{minipage}}
```

in the first example.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the `lrbox` environment to catch the environment in a box we can later use to measure.

Then it's just a matter to make sure we place all these things at the right place.

I'm assuming here that the corner images on each side have the same width because placing them makes it very easy then.

This way, the images don't protrude into other text areas.

If you need access to the optiona argument of the `minipage` environment, the environment definition needs to be adjusted, of course.

I've also made it so that the whole construct is its own paragraph but the details can be changed later still.

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox\@tempboxb
\NewDocumentEnvironment{minipagewithfourimages}{m mmmm}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxb}%
    \begin{minipage}{#1}%
}{%
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \par\noindent\leavevmode\noindent
  \rlap{\raisebox{\ht\@tempboxb}{#2}}%
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#3}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\dp\@tempboxb-\ht\@tempboxa}{\usebox\@tempboxa}%
  \usebox\@tempboxb
  \rlap{\raisebox{\ht\@tempboxb}{#4}}%
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#5}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\dp\@tempboxb-\ht\@tempboxa}{\usebox\@tempboxa}%
  \par
}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\begin{minipagewithfourimages}{8.5cm}{\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}}
                                     {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-b}}
                                     {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-c}}
                                     {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{minipagewithfourimages}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]